# Slideshow image from JSON

Tags: c#, json, image, uwp, slideshow

I want to create an image slideshow. The pictures are taken from data on json (as shown below).
[image: JSON]
I tried using the code below:

```
DispatcherTimer playlistTimer1a = null;
List<string> Images1a = new List<string>();

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    ImageSource1a();
}

private async void ImageSource1a()
        {
            try
            {
                var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
                httpClientHandler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
                string urlPath = "http://";
                var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("platform","win"),     
                };
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.PostAsync(urlPath, new FormUrlEncodedContent(values));

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string jsonText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JsonObject jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(jsonText);
                //JsonObject jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetObject();

                JsonArray jsonData1 = jsonObject["data"].GetArray();

                foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
                {

                    JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();

                    string image = groupObject1["image"].GetString();
                    string url = groupObject1["url"].GetString();

                    Banner file1 = new Banner();
                    file1.Image = image;
                    file1.URL = url;
                    Images1a.Add(file1.Image);
                    playlistTimer1a = new DispatcherTimer();
                    playlistTimer1a.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);
                    playlistTimer1a.Tick += playlistTimer_Tick1a;
                    topBanner.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file1.Image));
                    playlistTimer1a.Start();
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException ex)
            {
                RequestException();
            }
        }

 int count1a = 0;

void playlistTimer_Tick1a(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (Images1a != null)
            {
                if (count1a < Images1a.Count)
                    count1a++;

                if (count1a >= Images1a.Count)
                    count1a = 0;

                ImageRotation1a();
            }
        }

private async void ImageRotation1a()
        {
            OpacityTrans1.Begin();
        }
```

And the problem is only a slideshow displays the image index to 0 only, can not change the picture. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: I recommend you to use this library to handle json http://www.newtonsoft.com/json and this utility to create c# classes from json http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: my problem is cannot make slideshow image from json (can only take the first picture in the json, so the picture does not change, only flashes only). I use like the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And the problem is only a slideshow displays the image index to 0 only, can not change the picture.

The `foreach` loop break down everything.If you want to make slideshow images, don't include `DispatcherTimer` in `foreach` loop, you can revise your codes by following steps:

1. Modify your `ImageSource1a` method like below:

   ```
   private async void ImageSource1a()
   {
       try
       {
           ...
           foreach (JsonValue groupValue1 in jsonData1)
           {
               JsonObject groupObject1 = groupValue1.GetObject();
               string image = groupObject1["image"].GetString();
               string url = groupObject1["url"].GetString();
               Images1a.Add(image);
           }
              //I don't know what is Banner object used for but for this piece of codes, a banner object is not necessary.
               //Banner file1 = new Banner();
               //file1.Image = image;
               //file1.URL = url;

               playlistTimer1a = new DispatcherTimer();
               playlistTimer1a.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 6);
               playlistTimer1a.Tick += playlistTimer_Tick1a;
               topBanner.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Images1a[0]));//set the current image to the first one
               playlistTimer1a.Start();
       }
       catch (HttpRequestException ex)
       {
           RequestException();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Modify your `playlistTimer_Tick1a` method like below:

   ```
   private void playlistTimer_Tick1a(object sender, object e)
   {
       if (Images1a != null)
       {

           if (count1a < Images1a.Count)
               count1a++;

           if (count1a >= Images1a.Count)
               count1a = 0;
           topBanner.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Images1a[count1a]));
           ImageRotation1a();
       }
   }
   ```

**Update:** here is my basic demo: [SlideShowSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/SlideShowSample).

Comment: When I try to use code to replace the existing method ImageSource1a error like this picture: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4oRSWSS0hKDZUFWUzByemNtaEk/view?usp=sharing
How to handle it?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to comment out some codes, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I've tried the code for the method ImageSource 1a above, but the slideshow only flashes alone, the picture does not change (only the first image only). How to handle it?

Comment: You also need to update your codes for `playlistTimer_Tick1a` method. I added `topBanner.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Images1a[count1a]))` in this method.

Comment: I've update the codes for playlistTimer_Tick1a method. I added topBanner.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Images1a[count1a])) in this method. But, the slideshow only flashes alone, the picture does not change (only the first image only). How to handle it?

Comment: I've made a demo and add the link to my answer, you can compare it with your project. And find out what went wrong by your side.